# Proof of the Basic Proportionality Theorem

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

The following is my own attempt at proving the Basic Proportionality Theorem. Corrections and suggestions are welcome.

To prove: $\frac{\mathrm{\overline{A'B'} }}{\mathrm{\overline{AB} }}= \frac{\mathrm{\overline{B'C'} } }{\mathrm{\overline{BC} } }=\frac{\mathrm{\overline{A'C'}} }{\mathrm{\overline{AC}} }= \mathrm{K} $, where $\mathrm{K} $ is a constant.

[image: Figure 1]

Proof: In the above figure, $\Delta{\mathrm{A'B'C'} }$ is inscribed in the larger circle of radius $\mathrm{R'} $ and $\Delta{\mathrm{ABC} }$ is inscribed in the smaller circle of radius $\mathrm{R} $. Here, $\Delta{\mathrm{A'B'C'} }$ is the enlarged version of $\Delta{\mathrm{ABC} }$.

A well-known result from elementary geometry relates the arc length $l$ of a circle, the angle $\mathrm{\theta} $ subtended by the arc and the radii $\mathrm{R} $ joining the ends of the arc using the equation, $l=\mathrm{R\cdot\theta} $.

From the figure and the above result, we see that $\mathrm{arc A'B'} = \mathrm{R'\theta} $ and $\mathrm{arc AB} = \mathrm{R} \theta$, where $\mathrm{\theta} $ is $\angle{\mathrm{A'OB'}}$. Taking the ratios we get, $$\frac{\mathrm{arcA'B'}} {\mathrm{arcAB}} = \frac{\mathrm{R'}} {\mathrm{R}} $$

Similarly, $$\frac{\mathrm{arcB'C'}} {\mathrm{arcBC}} = \frac{\mathrm{R'}} {\mathrm{R}}$$ and $$\frac{\mathrm{arcA'C'}} {\mathrm{arcAC}} = \frac{\mathrm{R'}} {\mathrm{R}} $$

The diameter whose length is $\mathrm{D}$ is the longest chord of a circle. The other chords are scaled-down versions of the diameter. Mathematically, $$\mathrm{P} = \mathrm{B} \cdot  \mathrm{D} $$

Where $\mathrm{B} $ is a scaling factor—whose value is between $0$ and $1$—and where $\mathrm{P} $ is the chord length.

[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgEAg.jpg)

Let $\mathrm{P} $ in figure 2 be the diameter length. The length of the diameter changes from $\mathrm{D} $ to $\mathrm{D'} $. It is evident that the scaling factor is the same($\mathrm{B} =1$) in the larger circle and the smaller circle, for the ratio of the diameter lengths in each circle is $1$.

[Figure 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AzGR.jpg)

Now let $\mathrm{P} $ be the length of a chord that subtends an angle of $\frac{\pi} {3}$ radians at the center of a circle(see figure 3). The chord length is equal to the radius length of the circle, for the chord is a part of an equilateral triangle. As the chord length goes from $\mathrm{P} $ to $\mathrm{P'} $, it is, once again, evident that the scaling factor is the same($\mathrm{B} =\frac{1}{2}$) in the larger circle and the smaller circle, for the chord length in each circle is half of the diameter length.

We see a pattern. The pattern tells us that for a fixed $\theta$, the scaling factor is the same in every concentric circle. In other words, the scaling factor is independent of the radius length and is a constant for a constant $\theta$.

Following the pattern we have, $$\mathrm{P} \propto \mathrm{D} $$

This implies, $$\mathrm{P} \propto \mathrm{R} $$

This result and the result $l=\mathrm{R\cdot\theta} $(for constant $\mathrm{\theta} $) together imply, $$\mathrm{P} \propto l$$

Returning to F
figure 1 we see, $$\overline{\mathrm{A'B'} }= \mathrm{C} \cdot \mathrm{arcA'B'}$$

In the same sector, $$\overline{\mathrm{AB}} = \mathrm{C} \cdot \mathrm{arcAB}$$

Where $\mathrm{C}$ is a constant. Taking the ratios we get, $$\frac{\mathrm{arcA'B'}} {\mathrm{arc AB}} = \frac{\overline{\mathrm{A'B'}} }{\overline{\mathrm{AB}} } $$

Similarly, $$\frac{\mathrm{arcB'C'}} {\mathrm{arc BC}} = \frac{\overline{\mathrm{B'C'} } }{\overline{\mathrm{BC}} } $$

and

$$\frac{\mathrm{arcA'C'}} {\mathrm{arc AC}} = \frac{\overline{\mathrm{A'C'}} }{\overline{\mathrm{AC}} } $$

The above results convey, $$\frac{\mathrm{\overline{A'B'} }}{\mathrm{\overline{AB} }}= \frac{\mathrm{\overline{B'C'} } }{\mathrm{\overline{BC} } }=\frac{\mathrm{\overline{A'C'}} }{\mathrm{\overline{AC}} }= \mathrm{\frac{R'}{R}} $$

Where $\frac{\mathrm{R'}} {\mathrm{R}} = \mathrm{K}$, a constant. This concludes the proof.

Comment: In the proportionality relation, it's not clear why $n$ can't be a (non constant) function of $R$.

Comment: @Anonymous_original, this is a nice observation. I will try to reason this. If $\mathrm{n}$ is a non-constant function, there will be intervals where either $\mathrm{n} >1$ or $\mathrm{n} <1$. In either case, we run into the problem of the chord length exceeding the diameter length for various values of $\mathrm{R}$. I hope that this was convincing enough.

Comment: Such intervals need not exist. There can be isolated points where $n$ is greater than or less than $1$.  Also you can have piecewise defined functions which will contradict your argument.

Comment: @Anonymous_original, I have taken a simpler, different approach this time. Kindly read my answer one more time and help me correct my mistakes, if any. Thank you for your valuable inputs. They really helped me realize that I complicated the problem a lot!

Comment: $B$ is not a constant. In fact, if a chord subtends an angle $\theta$ at the centre, then it is $sin(\theta/2)$. You probably meant for constant $\theta$ and have used this later on, but all those statements about $B$ aren't true if you don't mention this. Apart from this, it's alright.

Comment: @Anonymous_original, indeed for constant $\mathrm{\theta} $. I mentioned it later, but I think mentioning it earlier is necessary here. I'll go ahead and do that.

Comment: Further thought reveals another fallacy here. While defining the trigonometric ratios, we use the basic proportionality theorem itself to assert that they are independent of the actual length of the sides of the triangle. So the above argument ends up becoming circular.

Comment: I don't think "proportional" is the most appropriate word here. The chord length is a function of the angle it subtends at the center and the diameter of the circle to which it belongs.